# iScroll with footer and header fixed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll, css-position

If you enter http://gizeto.se/app_yellow/index.html you can see that iScroll scrolls the entire page. You can see the scroller lying over both the header and the footer. The scroller should only scroll the **content**, not the header and footer included.

I wan't to make this work because I need the fixed footer without using position:fixed - which still doesn't work on for example Android 2.1

I use iScroll 4 and my JS code is inside my data-role="content" div:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var myScroll = new iScroll('content');
                $(window).bind('resize', function () {
                // I also tried setting a height on the content div, but that didn't work either. Its commented out.
                //$.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="content"]').height('200px');

                    myScroll.refresh();

                });
            });
```

My data-role="page" element has the data-iscroll="enable" attribute, and my html code for the scrolling part is:

```
    <div data-iscroll="scroller" class="scroller">
        <div data-iscroll="scroller">
        <h3>Välkommen</h3>

        <div style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="images/video.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" class="rounded" title="" />
        </div>
        <br />

            Ticker AB är en arkitekturbyrå som arbetar inom ett brett fält av projekt, från stadsplanering till bostäder via kontor och handel. Vår styrka ligger i våra idéer och vår förmåga att hitta nya, ofta oväntade lösningar som stärker platser och ökar fastigheters värde.      <br /><br />
            Vi följer den globala utvecklingen inom hållbar samhällsutveckling och arbetar aktivt för att integrera hållbara lösningar i alla våra projekt.


        </div>
    </div>
```

Why does iScroll scroll the hole page and not just the content so that my footer can stay totally fixed without the use of position:fixed which isn't supported in all mobile browsers just yet.

Comment: You should check out jQM ScrollView http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/

Comment: @PhillPafford The footer isn't fixed there, it fades out then fades in when you stop scrolling, which isn't a "native solution" as i want it to be. That is why iScroll exist, am I right?

Comment: also check out the new jqm blog post on jqm 1.1, which will include reworked fixed header/footer.

Comment: @frequent I know this, that's why I want to solve it temporarely with iScroll. That's my issue.

Comment: with jQM $(document).ready() is not used, try using pageInit() Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this widget plug-in for a cleaner integration of iScroll and JQuery Mobile:

https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview

Answer (score 0):

As of now the header and footer cant be made fixed in the jquery mobile application like iscroller.The reason behind this is that the Header and footer are placed inside the page div of the jquery mobile appication where as in iscroller app the header and footer are not the part of the page div.However if we try to keep the header and footer outside the page div in the jquery mobile appication, it may cause error such as disabling of the textbox etc.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if this is way too obvious but just because it's not included in your code example I thought I'd ask...have you added an id of "content" to your data-role="content" div? That's obviously what your iscroll container should be, but the content div doesn't have a div id in the jqmobile documentation:

[Jquery Getting Started](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/about/getting-started.html)

If you have added that id (which obv. I'm sure you probably have) I'd definitely checkout Phill Pafford's comment above re using pageInit() instead of $(document).ready().